# Spring cloud data flow ,jdbc-sink-rabbit source code

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I only can find the source for `jdbc-sink` ([Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-jdbc)), but I can't find the source code for `jdbc-sink-rabbit` which used in spring cloud data flow.

Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jdbc-sink-rabbit` is the generated application when building the starter project.

```
./mvnw clean install -PgenerateApps
cd apps
```

You will find the generated `jdbc-sink-rabbit` under `apps` directory.

The build instructions are specified [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-jdbc#build)